# Java / Spring / Angular.js passing file path to controller

Tags: java, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc

I am trying to return a file from the server based on the path that I pass in through the dirFile parameter. But, I can't get the dirFile parameter to the controller.

Here is my controller on the server:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test/getFile/{dirFile}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void doDownload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, 
@PathVariable String dirFile) throws IOException { ...returns file }
```

Here is how I am currently making the call:

```
<a ng-href="/Web/test/getFile/{{encodeFileURL(filetree.currentNode.id)}}">Click here to download file</a>
```

The parameter populates fine and produces the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/Web/test/getFile/C%3A%5Capache-tomcat-7.0.54%5Clogs%5Cfile.log
```

Without the parameter the controller does it's job and returns a file that I have hardcoded, but I want to return the file that is passed in. I can't seem to get the controller to accept the parameter for the file path though, it always returns something like a 400 Bad Request Error. I have tried a bunch of different variations of spring handlers but can't find something that works. What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
It's something with the encoding. I think it's encoded with UTF-8 and the tomcat is using something else. I'm going to try to pass as JSON or something instead.

Comment: Post the exception stack trace. Also, I hope you're aware that this is a huge security hole: anyone can access any file of the server (or even of the other machines on the network) that is readable by the user running your server process.

Comment: Yea, I know. It's going to be limited to admins and a subset of available files. But with this one I only get the 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because by default Spring treats urls with extension as file names. Try setting the property `useSuffixPatternMatch` of       `handlerMapping`  to `false`.

If you use Java Configuration:

```
   public RequestMappingHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping() {
        RequestMappingHandlerMapping handlerMapping = super.requestMappingHandlerMapping();
        handlerMapping.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
   }
```

Comment: I'm not sure it's the routing handler that is the problem, and I don't really want to touch that anyways because I'm not sure it's repercussions on all other calls. 
Also, there are other calls that seem to do the same thing, it just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set the path variable name in the @PathVariable annotation. 
In your case: `@PathVariable("dirFile")`.